# Python pymodbus in gui class

Tags: python, class, methods, instance, modbus

I am trying to develop a python gui application which communicates with a PLC using pymodbus. Using the documentation from the website & what I've found online, I can easily communicate & everything works perfectly. I am struggling with how to incorportate all this into a gui class with various methods. I am new to python & oo programing as my background is in mechanical engineering.

Please have a look at the code below. I want to connect to the device with method 'modbusConnect' when the user clicks & button. Therefore I've created the 'client' instance of ModbusTcpClient.

How can I then reference this instance in the 'dialValueChanged' method to read or write to a register. Please let me know if the structure of my code is incorrect & I should have various classes & etc.

Thank you in advance.

David

```
from pymodbus.client.sync import ModbusTcpClient
import struct
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui, uic

form_class = uic.loadUiType("C:\Users\David\.PyCharm30\VC-22D Modbus TCP\UI Design\Modbus-     MainScreen.ui")[0]
form_class2 = uic.loadUiType("C:\Users\David\.PyCharm30\VC-22D Modbus TCP\UI Design\Modbus- ConnectMenu.ui")[0]

class MyWindowClass(QtGui.QMainWindow, form_class):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self, parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.setFixedSize(1500,1200)
        self.dial.valueChanged.connect(self.dialValueChanged)
        self.pushButton_Connect.clicked.connect(self.modbusConnect)
        self.label.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon("C:\Users\David\.PyCharm30\VC-22D Modbus TCP\UI  Design\Cla-Val_30px.png"))

    def modbusConnect(self):
        #modbus connection
        ipaddress = str(self.lineEdit_IP.text())
        client = ModbusTcpClient(ipaddress)
        testconnection = client.connect()
        if testconnection == True:
            print ("Connection Successful")
        else:
            print ("Connection Not Successful")
            print (self.lineEdit_IP.text())
            exit()

    def dialValueChanged(self):
        setvalue = float(self.label.text())
        if setvalue == 0:
            setvalueint = 0
        else:
            setvaluehex = str(hex(struct.unpack('<I', struct.pack('<f', setvalue))[0]))
            setvaluehexstr = setvaluehex[:-4]
            setvalueint = int(setvaluehexstr, 16)


app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
myWindow = MyWindowClass(None)
myWindow.show()
app.exec_()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turn the `client` into an instance attribute of this GUI:

```
def modbusConnect(self):
    #modbus connection
    ipaddress = str(self.lineEdit_IP.text())
    self.client = ModbusTcpClient(ipaddress)
```

You can then refer to it from `dialValueChanged`:

```
def dialValueChanged(self):
    [... 7 lines omitted from output ...]
    self.client.write_coil(some_register, setvalueint)  #write_coil or write_register, depends on your communication
```

However, this means the GUI class is not fully instantiated when it is created. You should add some failsafes for when the `pushButtonConnect` is clicked again as well.

Comment: Makes sense! Thank you very for the response. Much appreciated! - David